# How to create in Django Admin something like stack inline but without foreign key?

Tags: python, django

```
class Data(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, unique=True)
    name = models.CharField(null=False, max_length=250)


class OtherData(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, unique=True)
    something = models.CharField(max_length=250)
```

How to create in Django Admin something like stack inline but without foreign key?
If I review `Data` object in admin page I want see also `OtherData` object (belonging to the same user)

Comment: I am not sure if I understand the question. However, if you want to manage Data and OtherData on the same form, then (1) use the User model in the admin and (2) add two stack inlines on Data and OtherData. Finally, (3) exclude all the files of the user.

Comment: No worries. I post posted my comment as an answer with a sample code.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to manage Data and OtherData on the same form, then:

1. use the User model in the admin and
2. add two stack inlines on Data and OtherData.
3. exclude all the files of the user or just let the username as
   read_only for reference
4. you probably have to unregister the User model and register it again
   because, as far as I know, it can just be registered once.

Here is a sample code

```
from django.contrib.admin import StackedInline
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from models import Data, OtherData

class DataInline(StackedInline):
    model = Data
    #form = you can customize your form
    #max_number = define the number of inlines

class OtherDataInline(StackedInline):
    model = OtherData

class UserAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = (DataInline, OtherDataInline,)
    fields = ('username',)
    readonly_fields = ('username',)

#the user can be regitered just once in the admin
admin.site.unregister(User)
admin.site.register(User, UserAdmin)
```

You might want to try a TabularInline if a user have more than one Data or OtherData. In other words, if you have a One to Many relation in the model. The flexibility of the Inlines is incredible.